# Calculations are performed on rasters within a range of values in raster data in R

Tags: r

I want to multiply by 2 the pixel values in a raster that are greater than 10 and less than 20. I try to using "d11[10<d11<20]<-d11*2", but it fails.

Comment: Is d11 from a dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: d11 is a geotiff as a raster data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm likely the worst person to be answering raster questions, but:

```
library(terra)
lil_rast <- rast(matrix(1:10, nrow=10, ncol=10))
plot(lil_rast)

lil_rast2 <- ifel(lil_rast > 4 & lil_rast < 6, lil_rast *2, lil_rast)
plot(lil_rast2)
```

In the ifel (terra's ifelse), if the values in lil_rast are > 4 and < 6,
multiply those values in lil_rast by 2, if not, do nothing. Which the plots seem to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are so humble that you solved my problem by proposing a solution！

Comment: Then I'd humbly request you accept the answer as answered questions help future searchers.